# How does 3D plotting works in OCaml

Tags: opengl, plot, 3d, ocaml, glut

I'm currently following a course of advanced functional programming using OCaml. For the programming project I have the task of implementing a 3D plotter that will be used for graphing functions. I'm getting started with lablgl and GLUT but unfortunately I haven't found good tutorials on GLUT using OCaml. I've managed to plot a 2D graph in a very naive way. I figure it's probably not the right way to do it as I don't really understand what I'm doing. Could someone please help me understand what's the strategy for 3D plotting using GLUT? I'm really stuck when trying to implement a 3D version of what I've done.

Here's the code I'v written for plotting a function in in 2D.

```
open Gl;;
open GlMat;;
open GlDraw;;
open GlClear;;
open Glut;;

(* Transform RGB values in [0.0 - 1.0] to use it with OpenGL *)

let oc = function
    x -> float x /. 255.
;;

(* The function to be graphed *)

let expression = function
    x -> sin (10. *. x) /. (1. +. x *. x)
;;


(* The rendering function drawing 2000 points in 400x400 canvas *)

let display () =
  GlClear.color (oc 255, oc 255,oc 255);
  clear [`color];
  load_identity ();
  begins `lines;
  GlDraw.color (oc 0, oc 0, oc 0);
  List.iter vertex2 [-1.,0.; 1.,0.];
  List.iter vertex2 [0.,-1.;0.,1.];
  ends ();
  begins `points;
  for i=0 to 2000  do
    let  x = (float i -. 1000.) /. 400. in
    let y = expression (x)  in 
    vertex2 (x,y);
  done;
  ends ();
  swapBuffers ();
  flush();
;;

(* general stuff and  main loop *)

let () =
  ignore (init Sys.argv);
  initWindowSize ~w:400 ~h:400;
  initDisplayMode ~double_buffer:true ();
  ignore (createWindow ~title:"Sin(x*10)/(1+x^2)");
  mode `modelview;
  displayFunc ~cb:display;
  idleFunc ~cb:(Some postRedisplay);
  keyboardFunc ~cb:(fun ~key ~x ~y -> if key=27 then exit 0);
  mainLoop ()
;;
```

Answer (score 2):

The best tutorial for GLUT, that I've seen so far, is the [Chapter 6](http://www.ffconsultancy.com/products/ocaml_for_scientists/visualisation/index.html) of OCaml for Scientists book. You probably might also seen [this tutorial](http://www.ffconsultancy.com/ocaml/bunny/) from the same authors. It may help you.

This libraries, as well as any other library implementing OpenGL in any other language are usually underdocumented, because it is assumed, that a user already knows how OpenGL works. So it might be a good idea, to start from some OpenGL book, and follow it using OCaml. In that case, [Tgsl](http://erratique.ch/software/tgls) library, that provides a thin OpenGL bindings to OCaml, will work better.

Last, but not least, OpenGL visualization is not the best idea for final project in functional programming course. OpenGL is very imperative by its nature and has nothing to do with functional programming. Also, you will learn nothing about using OCaml, as you will actually use OCaml as C.

If you still strive to do some visualization, then it might be a better idea to move away from OpenGL and 3d graphics to 2d and use declarative [Vg](http://erratique.ch/software/vg) library, that is purely functional.

Comment: Thank @ivg for your kind comments. I will look into Vg for the 2D visuization. Unfortunatelfy the 3D visualization is a requirement as well. The idea is to be able to work with about any library in available in OCamel. So, if someone has a better idea for 3D in OCaml that doesn't rely on OpenGL that'd be nice!